# Xcode 4.5 hides the tab bar in full screen mode! Can this be fixed?

Tags: tabbar, xcode4.5

I just installed Xcode 4.5 and notice that when I'm in full screen mode, the Xcode tab bar disappears along with the menu bar.  It used to remain visible even when the menu bar went away.  Does anyone else experience this?  Has anyone found a preference to keep the tab bar visible?

Comment: Same problem here. It's just soooooo annoying. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549167/xcode-4-5-tabs-disappear-when-app-is-running

Comment: no problem for me, I use <option> + <enter> combo. but changing tabs now laggggggs badly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that if you turn off full screen and turn it back on, things return to normal.  This seems to be a post-upgrade glitch that seems to fix itself.

Comment: It doesn't fix itself for me when I launch an app - as I move in and out of the Xcode space because of app runs, it still hides the tab bar.

Comment: Yes, worked for me. Edit: until I run an app, then it starts hiding again. FFS Xcode-team. EVERY RELEASE a new ridiculous bug.

Comment: Yikes!  I hadn't noticed that. Well the full screen toggling seems to work.  Also, I'm getting good at cmd-} and cmd-{ to cycle through the tabs.

Comment: It never seems to "fix itself", but Chuck's tip saves the day. It is frustrating as you can work fine in full screen mode and see the tabs, but if you swipe to another screen and come back the tabs are gone again.