# Xcode 4.5 Tabs Disappear When App is Running

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.5

Updated: It looks like whenever Xcode 4.5 is starting to run an app, the View -> Hide Tab Bar command will automatically get executed... It really looks like a bug.

The word **tabs** in this question refers to the one we see at the top of the **Xcode IDE**. Not the tab bar class in Cocoa Touch.

I'm running Mountain Lion 10.8.2 + Xcode 4.5(4G182). I found an annoying problem.

- In Xcode full screen mode, I like to open multiple tabs when I'm working on my iPhone project (1st screenshot)
- The tabs works great (just like any tabs we see in Safari or Chrome) before I upgraded to Xcode 4.5
- In Xcode 4.5 full screen mode, whenever I'm to run my apps (either on real devices or on simulator), the tabs will automatically be hidden as soon as I press the Run button or hit the keyboard shortcut (command + r) (2nd screenshot)
- If I'm working in non-full-screen mode, there will be no such problem.

Any idea why? How can I fix this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: My tabs are hidden even when it's not running in full screen.  It'll show if you move your mouse near the top of the window.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer I tried non-full-screen mode it works ok. It looks like a full-screen-mode-only problem to me

Comment: This is a new bug introduced by Xcode 4.5 and it is really maddening.  The workaround is to bounce back to non-full-screen and return to full-screen to make them display again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news, the latest update, Version **4.5.1** (4G1004) fixed this bug. :)

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

This is xcode functionality, Its not a bug.

xcode hide tabs on full view mode.

Comment: Yes it's a Bug. It used to work and worked great in previous Xcode releases. Put Xcode aside, can you imagine Safari or Chrome without tabs in full screen mode? I can't.

Comment: On the other hand, if this is a feature not a bug. Why Xcode 4.5 doesn't hide the tabs as soon as it enters the full screen mode, but rather hides it only when the developer hits the Run button when in full screen mode?

Comment: I agree with the original poster that this is a bug. As he says, this does not happen immediately on entering full screen, but only after you do a build and run in full screen. That would be a very strange feature if it was one.

Comment: Bug filed with Apple: Bug ID# 12423330